# App sign up for in-app billing on Android

Tags: android, google-play

I created an app and put it in the Android market.
I had my public key from the market and I put that in `base64EncodedPublicKey` in `Security.java`.

1. I'm confused about the signing up of the app. The google docs says it should use the same key for signing the apk. Is this the public key, my password, or something else?
2. Should I create the apk and upload it to my devices and the market?

Answer (score 0):

Movend Is A 3rd party inapp site that will help you Application Payable

GoTO This SIte[Check It](http://www.movend.com/)

Check This it describes How to Register An AndroidApplication [Clickhere](http://developer.movend.com/movend-development-centers/android/)

Comment: i cannot use any other third party payment because my client had asked to strictly use google gateway only...

Answer (score 0):

The base64EncodedPublicKey is only used for in-app billing purpose.

not signing apk file with that key.

use the eclipse to create the private key to sign the apk and upload to the market

Comment: what this private key should be? is there any restrictions for that?

Comment: So should you leave that key empty in the security.java when publishing? I´m not getting a response from the market, that´s why I´m asking.